# The best way to update entity in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm new to spring boot and trying to make my first api. I've made a lot of apis on python using FastAPI framework, but now i decided to study this technology. But here, I met a problem. So I'm using the jpa for database communication and I don't really understand how to update entity's fields correctly.

I've read a lot of guidelines, and all of them says that updating an entity carried out like this:

```java
    public void updateUserInDatabase(long userId, UserUpdateModel newData) {
        UserEntity user = userRepo.findById(userId).orElseThrow();
        if(newData.getUsername() != null) {
            user.setUsername(newData.getUsername());
        }
        if(newData.getPassword() != null) {
            user.setPassword(newData.getPassword());
        }
    }
```

But I think it's not useful as `newData` can have a lot of fields, so for updating an entity I'll need a lot of conditions.

So, yeah, maybe this question is not good, but I really try to understand XD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an entity mapper like [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) or [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/)

A ModelMapper example:

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
// this will tell ModelMapper to ignore null fields when mapping the source (newData) to the destination (user)
mapper.getConfiguration().setSkipNullEnabled(true);

UserEntity user = userRepo.findById(userId).orElseThrow();
// this will tell ModelMapper to map newData into user
mapper.map(newData, user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not bad, you want to make it better, but you are already doing it, like it is supposed to be done.

However, having a lot of fields in a table, could indicate a problem in the DB design, if you are not using Cassandra or something like that.